# C# : Whether this approach is thread-safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, thread-safety

I have a service class, which does request to some external service. That external service requires sessionId, time of live of this sessionId is unknown (can be some seconds, can be minutes, can be hours, can be days. Can be 1 request, can be 1000 requests. Nobody knows it. We can't link to it at all).

I created a method, which get sessionId:

```
    private async Task<string> LoginAsync()
    {
        using (HttpClient clientLogin = new HttpClient())
        {
            //....
        }
        return sessionId;
    }
```

I declared the following variable inside my class

```
public class BillComService : IBillComService
{
    private static Lazy<string> SessionId;
```

and init it in constructor:

```
    public BillComService()
    {
        if (SessionId == null)
            SessionId = new Lazy<string>(() => LoginAsync().Result);
        //....
    }
```

then I use it inside my methods:

```
    private async Task<T> Read<T>(string id, string endpoint)
    {
        var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("devKey", devKey),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sessionId", SessionId.Value)
            };
```

ok, it's fine.
Think about sessionId is expired. Method with throw `BillComInvalidSessionException`

Right now I wrote the following method to repeat my request after calling `LoginAsync` method if sessionId is expired.
Common method:

```
    private async Task<T> Retry<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
    {
        try
        {
            return await func();
        }
        catch (BillComInvalidSessionException)
        {
            SessionId = new Lazy<string>(() => LoginAsync().Result);
            return await Retry(func);
        }
    }
```

and for `Read`:

```
    private async Task<T> ReadWithRetry<T>(string id, string endpoint)
    {
        return await Retry(async () => await Read<T>(id, endpoint));
    }
```

so, my public method is:

```
    public async Task<Customer> GetCustomerAsync(string id)
    {
        return await ReadWithRetry<Customer>(id, "Crud/Read/Customer.json");
    }
```

it works and work fine. But I'm not sure, whether it's thread-safe :)

Comment: Why are you checking if `SessionId` is null in ctor? How could it not be `null` when you just constructed the object? Anyway, worst case scenario you will have 2 requests that will time out at the same time and will issue 2 parallel login requests. Could you end up with 2 different session IDs? That will depend on the remote service issuing the session token I guess. It could be problematic if the remote service issues different tokens upon subsequent login requests and invalidates the previous one (e.g. by the same you retry the token could be invalid already).

Comment: because `SessionId` is static field, so, it can already have value when we are creating new object. Therefore we can't get 2 different session ids. The worst case - 2 parallel login requests, but `SessionId` always will be one :)

Comment: Oh right, I had not noticed it was static. Still whether or not this code is problematic depends on how the remote service issues sessions. If subsequent logins invalidate previous sessionId then you may hit inefficient retry loops.

Comment: @plalx can be active several `sessionId` at the same time

Comment: Well in that case the worst that should happen is two or more concurrent logins. Still, if the remote login implementation changes then it could make your code very inefficient when negotiating new sessions concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't perform any kind of synchronization and allows for one or more logins issued in parallel. Whether this is a problem or not is entirely dependent on the remote implementation issuing the session IDs.

Here's the 3 main scenarios I can think of:

1. The remote login process synchronizes the session ID generation per developer's key and is guaranteed to return the same session ID for concurrent logins.
2. The remote login process will issue a new session ID per login, even in contention scenarios, but all session ID will remain valid.
3. The remote login process will issue a new session ID per login, but each subsequent logins are invalidating previously issued session IDs for a given developer's key.

With scenarios 1 & 2, the worst that can happen are inefficiencies (e.g. unnecessary network IO) due to concurrent login processes.

However, with scenario 3 then things could get ugly as you may end with many retry loops since session IDs could get invalidated right after being issued. The more concurrent requests there are with an invalid session and the worst it would get.

If you want to make sure that your code is safe independently of the remote implementation then you would have to synchronize the `SessionId` read & writes, which involves synchronizing the login process as well. Still, the remote implementation behavior is part of their service contract so it can also be reasonable for your implementation to take that behavior into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not thread safe.

You have a race when multiple threads set the shared `SessionId` field in parallel and another one when one thread is setting `SessionId` while other threads are using it.

BTW: it seems you are missing an wait when calling LoginAsync().

Comment: @OlegSh That's really depends on your definition of "thread safe"... Code in the question uses single string that is already immutable so you can't really have incomplete/corrupted state. You obviously can have multiple thread setting the same value... but this usually not considered "not thread safe" (sub-optimal maybe, but nothing wrong with updating same property multiple times).

Comment: Klaus, showing example when updating value of string can cause thread safety issues would be nice (I don't think you can actually come up with one so :) )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, seems to me, I can get 2 requests simultaneously in the worst case, but no corrupted state...

Comment: Oleg, a solution mostly depends on the answer to the questions: 1) would it harm to Login again (suferfluously) while the previous SessionId is still valid? 2) If two threads both log in in parallel and get two different SessionIds, are both valid for subsequent access?